# Getting PCM data from MP3 on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3, decode

I am interested in doing some music analysis on the Android platform. To do this, I want to parse an arbitrary MP3 into PCM data. I've looked around and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. One solution I've tried is using [jLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html). This works, but it is incredibly slow, decoding the song in the same time it takes to play it.

I know there exists an MP3 decoder on Android, Google says so itself under supported media types. Does anyone know how to use the Android decoder to decode an MP3 without actually playing it? All I want to do is divert the bits away from the DAC and store them in some buffer instead.

Alternatively, has anyone had any success using the NDK and something like [MAD](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/)? Are the performance gains that good?

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: I ended up using JLayer (http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html). It's slow, but it worked.

Comment: hi, I am able to convert to pcm but the values I get while writing to file is 0000 1120 992d ff00 e44a 1124 1122 122c when I save them as int and trying to play them it is not working.. any idea how?

Comment: I don't really know what you're doing and am not able to debug your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile and use LAME decoder. It works fine on ARM. And since its C/C++, performance would be better.

Hardware decoder on most ARM platforms are geared towards playback. So would not give you perfect PCM. E.g., to avoid jitter it would skip some data if load is high.

Instructions on compiling LAME are:

[Lame MP3 Encoder compile for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632835/lame-mp3-encoder-compile-for-android)