# Lame MP3 Encoder compile for Android

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I want to compile the lame encoder for Android. How can I find the tutorials for Lame and its compiling for Android platform.

Thanks,

Comment: follow this link http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000090

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There used to be a good [blog post](http://blog.libertadtech.com/2011/02/porting-lame-encoder-to-android-arm.html) on how to compile lame for Android, but for some reason it's been offline for a while and only available on some dodgy Chinese sites.

I'll just copy the content below:

> **porting compiling lame encoder to Android ARM arch using Android NDK**
>
> I was looking for a mp3 encoding application in Android Market,
> and found very few, the reason I think Android doesn't support mp3
> encoding is because mp3 is patented technology. Another reason is I
> guess people prefer Java programming and Android SDK rather than
> Android native development kit.
>
> Nevertheless compiling libmp3lame library for Android using Android
> NDK is very easy actually.
>
> 1. download Android NDK(also you need Android SDK and Eclipse with ADT plugin) and create simple project.
> 2. create directory called "jni" in your project's directory.
> 3. download lame sources, extract, copy all sources from directory libmp3lame to jni directory. Also copy lame.h which is located in include directory of lame sources.
> 4. create jni/Android.mk file. it should look like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)`
LOCAL_MODULE    := mp3lame
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bitstream.c fft.c id3tag.c mpglib_interface.c presets.c  quantize.c   reservoir.c tables.c  util.c  VbrTag.c
   encoder.c  gain_analysis.c lame.c  newmdct.c   psymodel.c
   quantize_pvt.c set_get.c  takehiro.c vbrquantize.c version.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

> 5. clean lame sources, remove what's left from GNU autotools, `Makefile.am`, `Makefile.in`, `libmp3lame_vc8.vcproj`, `logoe.ico`, `depcomp`, folders `i386`, `vector`.
> 6. edit file `jni/utils.h`, and replace definition `extern ieee754_float32_t fast_log2(ieee754_float32_t x);`
>    with this `extern float fast_log2(float x);`
> 7. go to the root directory of your Android project and run `$pathtoandroidndk/ndk-build` and you're done, you'll have `limp3lame.so` compiled.

Also, the following question on SO might be of interest for you, as it deals with some issues after compiling lame for Android:

- [Invoking native functions of ported library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896464/invoking-native-functions-of-ported-library)

Comment: 1. Don't remove vector floder; 2. Some source include lame.h using "lame.h" some source using <lame.h>, so you must add -I./ flags in Android.mk

Comment: How to compile it as a static library that can be used with ffmpeg?

Comment: I'm having an mp3 file with just noise like radio without signal after converting any webm/wav

Answer (score 10):

The above solution worked for me except:

- don't delete the `vector` directory from the source directory
- you can get rid of the compile warnings by adding a compiler flag: `LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DSTDC_HEADERS`