# Incompatible Implicit Declaration of Built-In Function Warning Using NDK with LAME

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface, mp3, lame

I'm trying to follow the tutorial located at the following location

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-using-LAME-MP3-on-Android-with-JNI

The gist of this is that it allows one to use the LAME MP3 encoder with JNI.

I followed each of the steps mentioned in the tutorial. My project is located at

```
C:\workspace\
```

and is called 'LAME_Test'. Per the section labeled **Compilation with NDK** in the tutorial, I went ahead and made a makefile called 'Android.mk' as is enclosed below this post.

I'm running Windows 7 on a 64-bit machine. I do have Cygwin and NDK installed and have tested that my setup works on another project that I'm working on. However, when I go to

```
/cygdrive/c/workspace/LAME_Test/jni
```

on Cygwin and issue the following command

```
 /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
```

given that the NDK is located at

```
C:\Android\android-ndk-r8b
```

the compilation spits out a bunch of warnings like these

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset' [enabled by default]
```

I'm enclosing a small snippet of the warnings at the bottom of this post (because the list of warnings is really big and may just add clutter - rather than add value).

Was wondering if there's a slick way to resolve these warnings and get a nice, clean, compile.

**P.S:** I will add that I was able to build + run the sample project in the link above (LAME4Android). This required the compilation of the native code. So, it looks like the the project does, in fact, build fine *despite all the warnings*. I initially thought it was broken because of the warnings. However, it would indeed be really great if there were some way to fix the warnings.

**Contents of Android.mk File**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE        := libmp3lame
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
    ./libmp3lame/bitstream.c \
    ./libmp3lame/encoder.c \
    ./libmp3lame/fft.c \
    ./libmp3lame/gain_analysis.c \
    ./libmp3lame/id3tag.c \
    ./libmp3lame/lame.c \
    ./libmp3lame/mpglib_interface.c \
    ./libmp3lame/newmdct.c \
    ./libmp3lame/presets.c \
    ./libmp3lame/psymodel.c \
    ./libmp3lame/quantize.c \
    ./libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.c \
    ./libmp3lame/reservoir.c \
    ./libmp3lame/set_get.c \
    ./libmp3lame/tables.c \
    ./libmp3lame/takehiro.c \
    ./libmp3lame/util.c \
    ./libmp3lame/vbrquantize.c \
    ./libmp3lame/VbrTag.c \
    ./libmp3lame/version.c

    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Log of Incompatible Implicit Declaration of Built-In Function Warnings**

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
Cygwin         : Generating dependency file converter script
Compile thumb  : mp3lame <= bitstream.c
Compile thumb  : mp3lame <= encoder.c
C:/workspace/LAME_Test/jni/./libmp3lame/encoder.c: In function 'lame_encode_frame_init':
C:/workspace/LAME_Test/jni/./libmp3lame/encoder.c:202:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset' [enabled by default]                                                                                                 
C:/workspace/LAME_Test/jni/./libmp3lame/encoder.c: In function 'lame_encode_mp3_frame':
C:/workspace/LAME_Test/jni/./libmp3lame/encoder.c:471:17: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'bcopy' [enabled by default]                                                                                                    
Compile thumb  : mp3lame <= fft.c
Compile thumb  : mp3lame <= gain_analysis.c
and so on...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a lot of searching it looks like the answer I was looking for was found here

[Lame MP3 Encoder compile for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632835/lame-mp3-encoder-compile-for-android/8632948#8632948)

The key for me was to ensure that the following line was added to my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DSTDC_HEADERS
```

as mentioned by James Zhang.

I'm enclosing my complete makefile below this post so what I'm saying is perfectly clear.

**Contents of Updated Android.mk File**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE        := libmp3lame
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
    ./libmp3lame/bitstream.c \
    ./libmp3lame/encoder.c \
    ./libmp3lame/fft.c \
    ./libmp3lame/gain_analysis.c \
    ./libmp3lame/id3tag.c \
    ./libmp3lame/lame.c \
    ./libmp3lame/mpglib_interface.c \
    ./libmp3lame/newmdct.c \
    ./libmp3lame/presets.c \
    ./libmp3lame/psymodel.c \
    ./libmp3lame/quantize.c \
    ./libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.c \
    ./libmp3lame/reservoir.c \
    ./libmp3lame/set_get.c \
    ./libmp3lame/tables.c \
    ./libmp3lame/takehiro.c \
    ./libmp3lame/util.c \
    ./libmp3lame/vbrquantize.c \
    ./libmp3lame/VbrTag.c \
    ./libmp3lame/version.c 

    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
    LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DSTDC_HEADERS

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```