# How to add Lame 3.99.5 to Android Studio using NDK?

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, lame

I am new in Android NDK. I need to add the Lame library to Android Studio using NDK. I start my research and find out some useful link:

[Lame MP3 Encoder compile for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632835/lame-mp3-encoder-compile-for-android)

[How to link the “lame” mp3 encoder shared object to an Android studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793325/how-to-link-the-lame-mp3-encoder-shared-object-to-an-android-studio-project)

I successful but only with build the "armeabi". How can I build the other like: "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "mips", "mips64", "x86", "x86_64"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After 3 days getting stuck with the Android Studio + Lame + NDK. I figure out how to do this:

## Step 1:

Download NDK: http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

Download Lame library: http://lame.sourceforge.net/download.php

My Android Studio 1.5.1

My NDK: android-ndk-r10e (you need to set path in order to use it)

My Lame library: 3.99.5

Note: lame library after download may have format .gz instead of .tar.gz. In that case, feel free to change it to .tar.gz and extract it by using 7zip (two times).

## Step 2:

For example, your Project is "AudioRecorder". Create a folder name "jni" in side it. AudioRecorder/jni.

Copy all the libmp3lame folder (inside lame 3.99.5) to jni (you should replace its name to lame-3.99.5_libmp3lame).

Copy lame.h to AudioRecorder/jni/libmp3lame.

## Step 3:

Create the Android.mk in AudioRecorder/jni:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LAME_LIBMP3_DIR := lame-3.99.5_libmp3lame
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := mp3lame
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -ffast-math -I $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/bitstream.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/fft.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/id3tag.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/mpglib_interface.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/presets.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/quantize.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/reservoir.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/tables.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/util.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/VbrTag.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/encoder.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/gain_analysis.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/lame.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/newmdct.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/psymodel.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/quantize_pvt.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/set_get.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/takehiro.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/vbrquantize.c \
                   $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/version.c \
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

## Step 4:

Remove Makefile.am, Makefile.in, logoe.ico, depcomp, lame.rc and i386 directory.

## Step 5:

Edit file jni/lame-3.99.5_libmp3lame/util.h, and replace definition

extern ieee754_float32_t fast_log2(ieee754_float32_t x);

with this

extern float fast_log2(float x);

## Step 6:

Move out, press shift + right click on the folder AudioRecorder choose open command line window:

"ndk-build" (to run NDK build)

"ndk-build clean" (to clean all built of NDK)

## Step 7:

You may have some error like this:

```
"Cannot recognize <lame.h>"
```

replace all "#include " to "#include "lame.h""

```
"incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'xyz'"
```

add  and  to any files which have the problems (try to add at the top of the file below the first comment).

```
"undefined reference to 'index'"
```

go to files "id3tag.c" and "machine.h" comment the "#define strchr index"

## Step 8:

Create the Application.mk in AudioRecorder/jni:

```
APP_ABI := all
```

If there is not Application.mk with the "APP_ABI := all", NDK only build the "armeabi"
Add this file the application will build up:

"arm64-v8a"

"armeabi"

"armeabi-v7a"

"mips"

"mips64"

"x86"

"x86_64"

## Step 9:

After successfully build NDK, now you should have 2 new folder

"AudioRecorder/libs"

"AudioRecorder/obj"

Create the "jniLibs" in "AudioRecord\app\src\main" and copy all folders in "AudioRecorder/libs" to it.

Hope it may help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I am stuck at Step 7, Still getting the errors  "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'xyz'". I have added #include "lame.h" at the top after the file comments section.

Comment: @ErphanRajput: make sure that you only added "#include "lame.h"" and there is no "#include <lame.h>" in your file. Clean all by using "ndk-build clean" before you build it again. If it is still not success, try to move "#include "lame.h"" down little by little.

Comment: if somebody is struggling with C compile errors -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13307523/2122712

Comment: Thanks for your detailed tutorial. By the way, I encountered "undefined reference to index" and "undefined reference to bcody". This could be solved by adding C flag "STDC_HEADERS". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893149/android-ndk-for-x86-64-has-no-reference-for-bcopy-and-index