# No implementation found for void com.example in android Lame

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, lame

Hello friends im facing the error file compile lame library with android NDK tool.

i complete all steps from here ..[How to add Lame 3.99.5 to Android Studio using NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812738/how-to-add-lame-3-99-5-to-android-studio-using-ndk)

when im trying to use it then it throws 
No implementation found for example.com.project

[image]

or error in code :

[image]

Comment: Could you please let me know for which devices you are looking to do it?
As I already did this for armeabi and it not that much lengthy which approach you are following.

Comment: i need for armeabi  can u please give me the code..?

Comment: or i can give you my project if you can modify it for armeabi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/naman14/TAndroidLame use this sample code.

Try with this and if you get any issue please post.

Comment: i did the same bro  but in this example there a experimental gradil is used that cause my problem for for another library .

Comment: i need without experimental

Comment: It is running for armeabi but you have to ad androidLame module to your project instead of gradle dependency, also you have to use both of this
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.2'

Comment: can you explain how ...?

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        /* 1) Add the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */

    }

Comment: give me some time I'll post steps screenshots

Comment: @vikasdube Try this: https://github.com/anujjpandey11/Android-Lame-importing-project-guide

Comment: Thanks very much for this help bro

Comment: can i add u on fb or any other site for stay in link

Comment: Sure but please share questions here as it is a big platform so you'll always get variety of ans. https://in.linkedin.com/in/anujjpandey

Comment: after use it, Could it covert mp3 to wav?