# No Implementation found for native UnsatisfiedLinkError Exception Android JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to implement LAME for an Android App, but I keep getting the error:

```
W/dalvikvm(2472): No implementation found for native     Lcom/example/android/audio/util/LameWrapper;.init (IIIII)V

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: init
     at com.example.android.audio.util.LameWrapper.init(Native Method)
     at com.example.android.audio.util.LameWrapper.init(LameWrapper.java:22)
     at com.example.android.audio.util.Recorder$1.run(Recorder.java:51)
```

I followed the steps to the answer ([Lame MP3 Encoder compile for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632835/lame-mp3-encoder-compile-for-android)). I was able to generate the libmp3lame.so file. It is placed inside **/libs/armeabi**

I also created **Android.mk** file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LAME_LIBMP3_DIR := lame-3.99.5_libmp3lame

LOCAL_MODULE    := mp3lame
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/bitstream.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/fft.c         $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/id3tag.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/mpglib_interface.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/presets.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/quantize.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/reservoir.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/tables.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/util.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/VbrTag.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/encoder.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/gain_analysis.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/lame.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/newmdct.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/psymodel.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/quantize_pvt.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/set_get.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/takehiro.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/vbrquantize.c $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/version.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I used **-javah** to create the **com_example_android_audio_LameWrapper.h** file. I used the .h to create **com_example_android_audio_util_LameWrapper.c**:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_android_audio_util_LameWrapper_init(
    JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jint inSamplerate, jint outChannel,
    jint outSamplerate, jint outBitrate, jint quality) {
    if (glf != NULL) {
        lame_close(glf);
        glf = NULL;
    }
    glf = lame_init();
    lame_set_in_samplerate(glf, inSamplerate);
    lame_set_num_channels(glf, outChannel);
    lame_set_out_samplerate(glf, outSamplerate);
    lame_set_brate(glf, outBitrate);
    lame_set_quality(glf, quality);
    lame_init_params(glf);
}
```

The actual java wrapper **LameWrapper.java**:

```
public class LameWrapper {
    public static void init(int inSamplerate, int outChannel,
        int outSamplerate, int outBitrate) {
        init(inSamplerate, outChannel, outSamplerate, outBitrate, 7);
    }

    public native static void init(int inSamplerate, int outChannel,
        int outSamplerate, int outBitrate, int quality);
```

I created a "Recorder.java" object to load in the mp3lame library. The recorder object has a "start" method which calls on the functions from LameWrapper.

```
public class Recorder {
    static {
    System.loadLibrary("mp3lame");
    }

    public void start(){

        //starts a thread, sets some values

        LameWrapper.init(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, 2, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, 32);
    }
```

I then call on the Recorder object in my MainActivity.

I have searched through much of stack overflow and could not find the answer. Usually for the "no implementation found error", the files are being named incorrectly. However, I am fairly certain I named the packages correctly.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't really see the native `init` method declaration in your Java code.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally included the `encode` method when I was trying to include the `init` method. I have updated the code accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see at least one reason why this won't work: your `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` variable doesn't include `com_example_android_audio_util_LameWrapper.c`. Fix that, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that!

Comment: he already added "LOCAL_SRC_FILES" in Android.mk where he needs to add this ?

Comment: @AhmadArslan He has already added the variable, but its contents are wrong, this file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) may help.

search this section No implementation found for native LFoo;.myfunc ()V.